# Blender cycles stops rendering when I add a bevel node to the material

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I wanted to have some edge detection on a simple cube to debug this but creating new files and doing the same thing just ends up killing cycles every time. I don't even have to connect the node to anything it's instantly stopped cycles from showing anything except gray or whatever image was last rendered.

I'm on blender 2.81 and supported feature set

Comment: Unable to duplicate. Can you please post a blend file?

Comment: Hi. Please use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) if you want to provide files for us to check.